# How to find information in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm coming from a unix background where I've written some scripts using bash and bourne.  But I need to write some scripts using powershell and I'm having a hard time finding information.

For example, in *nix, I can do `man bash` and read all about how to use bash and I can do `man some_command` to read about a specific command.  So far, I found some powershell equivalents like `get-command` to see all available commands, but getting and using objects is really confusing me.

For instance, I'm trying to create a new scheduled task using powershell and found some sample code here on SO.  Here is a snippit:

```
$schedule = new-object -com Schedule.Service 
$schedule.connect() 
$tasks = $schedule.getfolder("\").gettasks(0)

$tasks | select Name, LastRunTime

foreach ($t in $tasks) {
  foreach ($a in $t.Actions) {
     $a.Path
  }
}
```

I understand what this script is doing, but without experience how would I know to do the following:

- Know to use `new-object -com Schedule.Service`
- Know that this object has a `.connect` method
- Know that this object has a `.getfolder` and `.gettasks` object

A lot of the code seems ambiguous to me, so where would I find out the above information natively using powershell?

Comment: You'd know about `Schedule.Service` from experience or asking others -- the same way you'd know that `crontab` was the way to do it on Unix. I learned about its methods by typing `$schedule.` and then pressing the Tab key to see what the completion options are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you found `Get-Command`. That's a good start it will show you the available cmdlets. There may be even more available after importing snapins/modules. Use `Get-PSSnapin -Registered` and `Get-Module -ListAvailable` to see additional modules that may be imported to give you even more cmdlets.

The nice thing about PowerShell is that the creators built in an alias system. One of the goals of it was to make it easier to learn  PowerShell when you have a bash/DOS background. For example if you type `man Get-Process` it will give you the documentation for the `Get-Process cmdlet`. To see all documentation for it use `man Get-Process -Full`. `man` doesn't actually exist, it is an alias for `Get-Help` which has the same functionality as `man` on UNIX/Linux. You can use the `Get-Alias` cmdlet to show the registered alias' and their definitions.

The script you found is working with a `COM` object. You can tell because of the `-com` parameter that was used for `New-Object` (which is actually short for `-ComObject`). Unlike .NET objects, `COM` objects are not built in to PowerShell however PowerShell has support for them the same way VBScript has support for them. The `Get-Member` cmdlet will unveil both .NET and COM type object members (properties and methods). More about `Get-Member` below.

The script you found uses the `New-Object` cmdlet to create an instance of the `COM` object named `Schedule.Service`. There are two main ways to find out more information about this object. The first is that you can list its properties and methods directly within PowerShell using the `Get-Member` cmdlet. This cmdlet works for both .NET and COM objects. It is an invaluable cmdlet that will show you what you can do with your objects. Use `man` or `Get-Help` `Get-Member` to learn about it. In fact you can use `Get-Member` to discover the object members you asked about such as the `.connect` method. The second way is to look up the documentation for the object on MSDN which is Microsoft's developer documentation website. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383607%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is probably the best page for that particular object.

Answer (score 2):

I am not  familiar with powershell scripting but found this, maybe some reference to use:

> - http://technet.microsoft.com/eng-us/scriptcenter/powershell%28en-us%29.aspx
> - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh857339.aspx#BKMK_wps4

On the first link are PowerShell Scripting Webcasts to find and more.

Scheduling Jobs with the Windows PowerShell API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj150476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Guide to getting started with Windows PowerShell: http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ee221100.aspx

About Windows PowerShell, following help topics:
  get-command  : Gets information about cmdlets from the cmdlet code.
  get-member   : Gets the properties and methods of an object.
  where-object : Filters object properties.
  about_object : Explains the use of objects in Windows PowerShell.
  about_remote : Tells how to run commands on remote computers.

Conceptual help files are named "about_", such as:
  about_regular_expression.

The help commands also display the aliases of the cmdlets. These
are alternate names or nicknames that are often easier to type.
For example, the alias for the Invoke-Command cmdlet is "remote".

To get the aliases, type:

get-alias

Hopefully this will help a little.

Answer (score 1):

The first hit on Google for "powershell create scheduled task" leads [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/710f1ca6-22df-4df6-b35c-2b012586245e/createmodify-scheduled-task-from-powershell-without-schtasksexe), where one of the answers refers to the `Schedule.Service` COM object. [That object's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383448.aspx) gives you a list of all the methods and properties of the object.

You can also use `get-member` to discover all the methods & properties of any variable or object in your session.

```
$schedule = new-object -com Schedule.Service


   TypeName: System.__ComObject#{2faba4c7-4da9-4013-9697-20cc3fd40f85}

Name            MemberType Definition
----            ---------- ----------
Connect         Method     void Connect (Variant, Variant, Variant, Variant)
GetFolder       Method     ITaskFolder GetFolder (string)
GetRunningTasks Method     IRunningTaskCollection GetRunningTasks (int)
NewTask         Method     ITaskDefinition NewTask (uint)
Connected       Property   bool Connected () {get}
ConnectedDomain Property   string ConnectedDomain () {get}
ConnectedUser   Property   string ConnectedUser () {get}
HighestVersion  Property   uint HighestVersion () {get}
TargetServer    Property   string TargetServer () {get}
```

The [Component Object Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) is a core piece of Windows and there are hundreds if not thousands of COM objects available in default Windows installation for interacting with both the OS and other software installed (software can install its own set of objects as well). A lot of it can be replaced with .NET Framework assemblies and PowerShell modules, snap-ins and cmdlets now.

How do you discover COM objects? Usually via Google - running searches for the things you're trying to do, and typically you'll find someone has already posted something about similar, or your search will key off words in the object's own documentation online.

If you're using PowerShell 3, you don't need to use `Schedule.Service` at all - there's a set of cmdlets for working with scheduled tasks. See [`New-ScheduledTask`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649810.aspx) for a starter.

If you're looking for a generic PowerShell tutorial, I usually point people [at this one](http://www.powershellpro.com/powershell-tutorial-introduction/)

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track in that `Get-Command *foo*` will list all Cmdlets containing the word foo, and `Get-Help New-Object` will show you the help file for the New-Object cmdlet.

However, you then go straight into using COM objects, which far predate Powershell. COM programming is old and can be quite archaic. Powershell lets you interface with COM, but it's not really the "Powershell way" of doing things.

In Powershell 3, I was able to find `Register-ScheduledJob`:

`The Register-ScheduledJob cmdlet creates scheduled jobs on the local computer.`

If possible I would say that is the preferred approach over using the COM interface, just because it's likely easier and more Powershelley.

Comment: Interesting.. So I want to avoid using `COM` objects where possible and stick with powershell cmdlets?

Comment: @nkon First look for a cmdlet that does the task you want to do first.  PowerShell is still relatively new (by bash standards), so it does not yet have a cmdlet for every task you might want to do which is why you may have to use .NET or COM objects directly. By the way a lot of cmdlets use these objects behind the scenes but give you a nice cmdlet to call instead of using the objects directly.